# How does ArcGIS modify a TIF file while georeferencing?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, georeferencing, geotiff-tiff

I have some images, . TIF files that I am georeferencing using ESRI's software ArcGIS. I would like to know how does the program modify the initial .TIF file when one uses the Update Georeferencing tool after finding adequate Control Points.
Is there a way to revert such a georeferenced TIF file to its initial (ungeoreferenced) state by modifying it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways ArcGIS puts the georeferencing to the tiff.

The one is to create auxiliary files where the transformation rules are stored. This can be achieved by using the option "update Georefrencing". If you want to reverse this you just delete all the files beside the original .tif file (there should be 3 or 4 others).

The second is called "Rectifiy". Here a single new raster is created with the transformed data. Here you keep the old file anyway.